# h2 database home

Tags: h2

I was looking into derby database and found property which sets derby home directory.

Are there property in h2 database like to `derby.system.home` to set home directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sonar on h2 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596530/sonar-on-h2-database)

Comment: Googling "sonar h2" brought up these two questions. I don't think this question stands on it's own in anycase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, H2 supports the system property [`h2.baseDir`](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/SysProperties.html), even thought I wouldn't actually recommend using it. Instead, I suggest to use either a hardcoded path in the database URL, such as `jdbc:h2:/data/dbs/test` or use a path relative to the user home directory, such as `jdbc:h2:~/dbs/test`.

Comment: what is wrong with it? why cant I use it? from my perspective it is very useful

Comment: You can use it of course, but you need to remember to set it every time. If the setting isn't set, a different database is created in a different directory, which might be confusing. That's why I don't recommend to use the setting - is to avoid such problems.